# How do I pair up rows of network traffic data in R or SPSS?

Tags: r, analysis, spss, network-traffic

I have lots of SiLK flow data that I would like to do some data mining on. It looks like the destination IP column matches the source IP column of a row of data further down. The rows (with many more columns) look like this:

```
UID SIP DIP PROTOCOL    SPORT   DPORT
720107626538    1207697420  3232248333  17  53  7722
720108826800    3232248333  1207697420  17  47904   53
```

I have never programmed in R or SPSS and am having trouble figuring out how to turn 2 rows of 27 columns of data into 1 row of 54 columns of data.

Comment: How do I get rid of the duplicate rows?

Comment: The DIP in one dataset is to be matched to the SIP in the second dataset, but only the very next match, sorted by UID.

Comment: What defines a duplicate *exactly*? If the other variables are the same, just the `SIP` and the `DIP` are in a different order?

Comment: It's the return flow, so it has different ports and the times are slightly in the future. I should say redundant instead of duplicate, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get corresponding SIP and DIP records on the same line through `merge`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "UID" = c(720107626538, 720108826800),
  "SIP" = c(1207697420, 3232248333),
  "DIP" = c(3232248333, 1207697420),
  "PROTOCOL" = c(17, 17),
  "SPORT" = c(53, 47904),
  "DPORT" = c(7722, 53),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_merged <- merge(
  df[,setdiff(colnames(df), "DIP")],
  df[,setdiff(colnames(df), "SIP")],
  by.x = "SIP",
  by.y = "DIP",
  all = FALSE,
  suffixes = c("_SIP", "_DIP"))
```

After that, you can use the UID fields to remove duplicates:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df_merged)) {
  ind <- df_merged$UID_DIP
  ind[i] <- df_merged$UID_SIP[i]
  df_merged <- df_merged[!duplicated(ind),]
}

df_merged

df_merged
         SIP      UID_SIP PROTOCOL_SIP SPORT_SIP DPORT_SIP      UID_DIP PROTOCOL_DIP SPORT_DIP DPORT_DIP
1 1207697420 720107626538           17        53      7722 720108826800           17     47904        53
```

Because the de-duping relies on a loop, the whole thing could get very time-consuming if your dataset is large.

Comment: If this was SQL, the FROM statement would look like this:
`FROM CyberDefense.dbo.flows AS flow1 INNER JOIN CyberDefense.dbo.flows AS flow2 ON flow1.DIP = flow2.SIP AND flow1.SIP = flow2.DIP AND flow1.UID < flow2.UID` How can I ensure that the right rows are being paired?

Comment: It's hard for me to come up with anything more than a general solution without more of the dataset, but my intuition would be to just call `merge`, let it match everything no matter what the UIDs were, and then call `subset(df_merged, UID_SIP < UID_DIP)` to remove all the erroneous matches. Depending on the size of your dataset, merging first and filtering later might not be practical.

Comment: The Windows GUI crashes when I type in `flows_merged <- merge(flows[,setdiff(colnames(flows), "DIP")], flows[,setdiff(colnames(flows), "SIP")], by.x = "SIP", by.y = "DIP", all = FALSE, suffixes = c("1", "2"))` - using `--max-mem-size` in the command line has no effect.

Comment: Hm. That might be a plain-old R-runs-out-of-memory problem. How big is your data set? As I said in my last comment, merging first and filtering second might not be practical (or, apparently, feasible). That means you'd need to figure out a way to filter first - I'd need to see more the data to take a stab at that.

Answer (score 1):

In SPSS, I would tackle this (from what I can gather in your comments and questions), by making a new id variable to ID the cases where the the lagged values of `SIP` and `DIP` correspond to one another, and then use `CASESTOVARS` to reshape the data long to wide.

```
******************************************************************.
*Fake data that looks like yours.
data list free / UID SIP DIP PROTOCOL  SPORT.
begin data
1 1207697420  3232248333  17  53
2 3232248333  1207697420  17 47904
3 1 2 5 6
4 2 1 3 2
5 1 3 0 1
6 1 4 8 9
end data.

*Can make our own new id to reshape.
DO IF $casenum = 1.
    compute new_id = 1.
ELSE IF SIP = lag(DIP) and DIP = lag(SIP).
    compute new_id = lag(new_id).
ELSE.
    compute new_id = lag(new_id) + 1.
END IF.

*then reshape from long to wide.
CASESTOVARS
/ID new_id.
LIST. 
******************************************************************.
```

This is assuming, as you said in your comment, that "The DIP in one dataset is to be matched to the SIP in the second dataset, but only the very next match, sorted by UID". The end result then looks like this (with periods representing missing data).

> new_id    UID.1    UID.2    SIP.1    SIP.2    DIP.1    DIP.2
>   PROTOCOL.1 PROTOCOL.2  SPORT.1  SPORT.2
>
> ```
> 1.00     1.00     2.00 1.2E+009 3.2E+009 3.2E+009 1.2E+009     17.00      17.00     53.00 47904.00
> 2.00     3.00     4.00     1.00     2.00     2.00     1.00      5.00       3.00      6.00     2.00
> 3.00     5.00      .       1.00      .       3.00      .         .00        .        1.00      .
> 4.00     6.00      .       1.00      .       4.00      .        8.00        .        9.00      .
> ```

It isn't clear from your initial question *what a duplicate is*, but if you don't want duplicates you will want to get rid of them before the `CASESTOVARS` I imagine. If it is defined by having the same values for the other variables, but just with an interchangeable `SIP` and `DIP`, one thing I have done in the past is to make two new variables, and place the smaller value in the first new field and the larger value in the second field. E.g.

```
DO IF SID >= DID.
    compute ID1 = DID. 
    compute ID2 = SID.
ELSE.
    compute ID1 = SID.
    compute ID2 = DID.
END IF.
```

Then you can use the two new `ID` variables to identify duplicates irrespective of the order of the original `SIP` and `DIP` values.